# Sefer and Tikkun L'Choleh

Tags: product-recommendation, jewish-books, choleh-sick

Someone sent me a pdf file of *tikkun l'choleh*. Does anyone know where I can purchase this *sefer*?

Answer (score 2):

If this is the right one, try [Divrei Chizuk](http://www.divreichizuk.com/id29.html) where she says,

> For more information, or to obtain one/or more of the booklets for
>   yourself or for another , please call Margie Shabat at 773-478-8325 or
>   e-mail me at: momchicago@aol.com

Comment: Is  773-478-8325 her cell number?

Comment: It's her Landline see http://www.allareacodes.com/reverse-phone-lookup/